# Visual Studio SSIS Script task - how to choose vs version to open file

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have an ssis package that is opened in VS 2017, containing a script task.

[image]

If I edit the task, it opens in another instance of VS, but this time VS 2019. Is there a way to specify the version of VS when editing the script task?

Comment: You have an excellent question and to be honest, I have no idea how it works and I've done a fair bit with SSIS. My guess was that it was based on the program associated to the [.vstax](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/02/slimming-down-ssis-script-task.html) extension but that falls down because I have nothing associated to that extension on my machine. Plus, I don't have those extensions in the 150/160 folders, just in the 110-140 subfolders of x86 Microsoft SQL Server.